# Adding Sizzle js to my project breaks the project

Tags: javascript, sizzle

I'm not entirely sure what's happening here. I have my code that exists like:

```
var mycode = {
    init:function(){
        //my code here
    }
}

//sizzle pasted here...
(function(){ //sizzle code here })();
```

Where "sizzle code here" is the copy/paste of Sizzle in its entirety. Sizzle is contained in an anonymous function, so I'm not sure what the interference is.

As soon as I add Sizzle in this manner, my js in the "mycode" object literal stops working and I get errors like "mycode is not defined". This happens in Chrome on Mac, Firefox 3.5.x, and Safari 4 Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code should be

```
   var mycode = {
        init:function(){
            //my code here
        }
   };

    //sizzle pasted here...
   (function(){ /*sizzle code here*/ })();
```

the missing semicolon after your 'mycode' object results as,

```
var mycode = { init:function() {}}(function(){/*sizzle code here*/ })();
```

which results in error ;)

Comment: I was scrolling through the google js style guide the other day, and saw exactly this problem described here: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#Semicolons

Comment: @Dan Manastireanu - this is a common mistake. It's great that 'Google Style Guide' covers it, so that JS newbies would be aware of such issues.

Answer (score 0):

Missing the closing paren for your function wrapper, should be:

```
(function(){ //sizzle code here })();
```

Comment: Thanks. That was an error in my question, unfortunately not the actual code.